# Defaulting to xml serialization in asp.net core

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, serialization

I'm trying to create a Web-Api based on asp.net core. My requirement is that, it should support `xml` serialization by default and not `json`.
I added

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

But still, the default serializer is json.
I need it to return `xml` without the client having to specify

```
{"Accept":"application/xml"}
```

Comment: Do you want the entire response to be XML or just objects inside response be XML.

Comment: I can also deal with the content/object alone as xml, as it is the content which is deserialized back to the object at the client program

Comment: When you deserialize the xml you need classes or have to create custom parser code..  Json you can serialize without classes.  So do you have the classes.

Answer (score 3):

As said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#forcing-a-particular-format), you must force your application to produce XML instead of JSON:

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    opt.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/xml"));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing default serializer, you could try

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddMvc(options => {
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```